# Firefox duplicate cookie  (Firefox bug?)

Tags: firefox, cookies

It's my understanding that if you send a cookie with the sane Name, Host, and Path, that it will be interpreted by the browser as a replacement.

This seems to be the case in Chrome, but in Firefox (7.01) I'm instead getting multiple cookies that are completely identical except for the content.

[image]

All 3 SqlAuthCookie entries are identical except for the "Content" part.

Is this a bug in Firefox or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how cookies work?

Comment: Can you show the code that sets the cookie?

Comment: @MarcB It's just the standard ASP.NET authentication, so I'm not explicitly setting it myself.  The cookie isn't being removed when logging out (although it is being invalidated server-side)

Comment: I also tried manually removing the cookie by explicitly assigning one with a past expiration date to no avail.

Comment: Can anyone else repeat this or is it just me?

Comment: No bites even with a bounty huh?

Comment: Do you also see the duplicate cookings if you just browse through the list? There have been problems reported that duplicates show up when using a filter, but not when you just browse through the list.

Comment: @Pieter Hmm, they appear to go away when I close the view cookie window.  The duplicates also appear when not filtered, but only when the node is collapsed and reopened.

Answer (score 9):

This only occurs if you keep the Cookie window open while the cookies are being set. Once you close and re-open the Cookie window, you should only see the latest value stored.

Similarly, if you delete a cookie while the Cookie window is open, it will still show up in the list until you close and reopen the Cookie window.

I'm speaking from experience - I've been frustrated by the same thing - unfortunately I don't have any proof, nor do I know if this is a bug or an intentional feature.

**Update**

Interestingly enough, Google Chrome behaves similarly. If you open the Options tab, the cookie values that are displayed under "All cookies and site data" do not change until you close and re-open the tab. I'm guessing this is an intentional feature for both browsers.

Comment: Giving this the bounty since it explains the issue (and because I was informed there was 58 seconds remaining on the bounty period)

Comment: See [Firefox bug #504086: Show Cookies manager does not refresh display properly](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504086)