# Multiple cookies with same name, domain and path?

Tags: firefox, cookies

Using Firefox 37.0.2, in the Cookies dialog I noticed that for a certain (non-public) web site there are multiple cookies with the same name, host (domain), path, attributes ("Send For") and expiry (but different value).

Why does Firefox keep all of them, should not the last one overwrite the older ones? Is there some property of them not shown in the dialog that makes them each different?

Note: the website uses/send a single cookie.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it is a bug/feature in Firefox. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8124860/822870

After closing and reopening the Cookies window, the duplicates disappear. It is enough to just change the search criteria (I erased the search string, the entered the same value, then only a single instance of each cookie was shown).

See [Firefox bug #504086: Show Cookies manager does not refresh display properly](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504086)